# Show that the set of all points $x \in \mathbb R$ where $f$ is differentiable is definable in $\mathcal M=(\mathbb R; +,-(), \cdot, \lt, 0,1,f)$

Tags: calculus, logic, model-theory

For the structure $\mathcal M=(\mathbb R; +,-(), \cdot, \lt, 0,1,f), n_f=1 $ show that the set of all points $x \in \mathbb R$ where $f$ is differentiable is a definable set.

My issue here is how to write a formula $\phi$ for this structure describing differentiability at a point, when the definition uses the limit definition. Do I need to describe the limit in the formula using $\epsilon, \delta$? Wouldn't that produce an extremely long formula?

Any assistance will be great.

Comment: Hint: expand away the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit notion and you will get a first order formula $\phi)(x)$  in the language of your structure beginning $\forall \epsilon > 0\exists \delta > 0\forall y$. It isn't very long, although you need to be careful to cater for the cases when $x < y$ and $y > x$.

Comment: So how about $ \phi (h, \epsilon, \delta,x_0):  \forall h>0 \ \forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ (f(x_0+h)-f(x)) \cdot \frac{1}{h} \in \mathbb R  $

Comment: You should probably use the quantified epsilon and delta somewhere in that formula...

Comment: Oops, got stuff mixed up! Thanks...

Comment: Jonny's comment is quite correct. Also the $\forall h$ needs to be the innermost quantification.

Comment: Perhaps: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0 \forall h: 0<h<\delta \Rightarrow 0<(f(x_0+h)-f(x_0))\cdot \frac {1}{h}-L<\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the derivative of $f$ exists at $x$ when the $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists.

The set of all such $x$ is definable by this formula: $$\exists L \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall h : (0 < |h| < \delta) \rightarrow (|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - L| < \epsilon) $$

We still are not done, because we don't have division or absolute value in the language. Can you show that these two operations are definable?

Comment: I believe you can express $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - L| < \epsilon$ as $-\epsilon < \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - L < \epsilon$ instead, and it  is in the language. As for division, $\frac {1}{h}$ is in $\mathbb R$, so it is just multiplying $f(x+h)-f(x)$ with  $\frac {1}{h}$, so why is showing 'division' is defined needed?

Comment: Well, $h$ is a quantified variable used elsewhere in the formula. So you need to demonstrate that $\frac{1}{h}$ is a definable function (which is perhaps easier to define than division, but division is definable too).